# gridview : Dynamic template fiel with text box

Tags: gridview

im using gridview to display records. Rows and columns are generated dynamically by using (pivot table - sql server ). I want to display textbox in each cells of the grid. Can anybody help me pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem get solved by using  GridViewTemplate : ITemplate.

Regards
Geetha

Answer (score 0):

This link should be exactly what you need.  I followed it and was able to display a text box in each cell of the grid dynamically.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/create_template_columns.aspx

If you know how many columns you'll need then the easiest way is just to use:

```
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ColumnName") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

You can create as many TemplateField columns as you like.  However if you need to create the columns dynamically and without knowing how many columns, use the link above.